# positioning and resizing div elements within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following [code](https://codepen.io/smrak/pen/dVKwvN) on CodePen and I'm trying to create a website from scratch. Each section is going to be its own full page which is the reason why I created the section class. Inside my first section (about), I've created two divs. Ultimately I would like for it to look like this no matter what size the browser is [image: this image]. When the window is resized, the contents should automatically resize to fit the screen as well. But the code I have so far moves the aboutInfo when the window gets smaller (even though I set the position to absolute).

My code so far:

```
#about {
  background-color: #D1C9BE;
  position: relative;
}

#aboutImage {
  border-style: dashed;
  border-color: red;
  background-color: white;

  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 300px;
}

#aboutInfo {
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: black;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: right;

  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 200px;
}
```

I've researched a few fixes and I've read that I can use Flexbox, jQuery, and even just a fix of margin and padding. At this point, I'm not sure which solution would work best and which would be easier to use.

So to summarize my questions:

1. How do I fix the position of aboutInfo to keep it from moving around?
2. How do I automatically resize the contents of the whole website to fit any sized browser?

Comment: What if the viewport is so small that you can't fit the text and the red rectangle? What will the layout strategy be?

Comment: So, you want both of those divs to stay exactly as they are positioned, but in the center of the screen?

Comment: Do you want the text inside the boxes to grow depending on the size of the screen?

Comment: @hermbit yes, but would love for it to automatically resize if the window gets smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
}

/* FULLPAGE */
.section {
    height: 100vh;
     display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}

/* ABOUT */
#about {
    background-color: #D1C9BE;
    position: relative;
}

#aboutImage {
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: red;
    background-color: white;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}

#aboutInfo {
    border-style: dotted;
    border-color: black;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: right;

}

#aboutInfo p {
    font-size: 15px;
}


/* SKILLS */
#section2 {
    background-color: #D8B17B;
}

/* PROJECTS */
#section3 {
    background-color: #9E9283;
}

/* OTHER */
#section4 {
    background-color: #70614C;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this styling, I have updated your css to use flex for positioning

```
   body {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
}

/* FULLPAGE */
.section {
    height: 100vh;
     display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;

}

/* ABOUT */
#about {
    background-color: #D1C9BE;
    position: relative;
}

#aboutImage {
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: red;
    background-color: white;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}

#aboutInfo {
    border-style: dotted;
    border-color: black;
    background-color: white;

    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: right;

}

#aboutInfo p {
    font-size: 15px;
}


/* SKILLS */
#section2 {
    background-color: #D8B17B;
}

/* PROJECTS */
#section3 {
    background-color: #9E9283;
}

/* OTHER */
#section4 {
    background-color: #70614C;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way to move these two div elements closer like the image above? I tried using left and right but it wasn't working.

Comment: Check my anwser below, with that you can just change the mergin left to put positioning as per your requiremnt. please mark that as answer if that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [**flex**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) to make responsive divs. **Do not** use absolute positioning for this.

Here is an updated [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rGKPdz).

```
.section {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 48px; /* adds space to edges of screen */
    align-items: center; /* vertical centering */
}

.section > :first-child {
    margin-right: 48px; /* sets distance between boxes */
}
```

[Here is a great article from MDN on using flex.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)